# mod_wsgi configuration issues

Tags: python, windows, apache, wamp, mod-wsgi

I have got some issues while setting up the `mod_wsgi` module in the WAMP Server w/ Apache 2.2. I downloaded this file `mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so` from the [official google code page](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list).

I put my module in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\modules` after renaming the file to `mod_wsgi.so`.

Then I added the following line among the load modules section:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

When I restart the Apache server, it doesn't run. When I checked the windows service event log, I found the following error.

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 128 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The Apache service named is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I’m using Windows 7 premium with Python 2.7 and Apache 2.2.

Please tell me where I might be going wrong.

Comment: Note that the downloads that you refer to only work for **32 bit** versions of Python and Apache. Are **both** your Python and Apache the 32 bit versions?

Comment: And was Python installed for all users? You cannot install it for just the user you installed it as, as Apache runs as different user.

Comment: Yes both Python and Apache are 32bit versions.

Comment: But was Python installed for all users? If you used the GUI based installer there is a checkbox. If you use batch installer, it by default only installs for current user. You would need to modify batch config file to install for all users.

Comment: Hey i found the problem. I accidentally downloaded the 64bit apache. That caused all the problem. I installed the 32bit and loaded the wsgi and got django running. Now its all fine :)